# Cookies / Recoger cookie e introducirla en variable

Tags: javascript

Por un lado deseo crear dos cookies: "nombre:Ana" y "sexo:mujer".
Por otro lado en la vista tengo un formulario con un campo input Nombre y otro campo input Sexo además de un botón "rellenar formulario".

Cuando se pulse el botón "rellenar formulario" deseo que el campo nombre se rellene con el contenido de la cookie 'Ana' y que el campo Sexo se rellene con el contenido de la cookie 'mujer'.

¿Cómo hago para introducir cada cookie dentro de una variable nombre y de otra variable sexo en javascript?

Respondiéndome a esta pregunta creo que el resto de la funcionalidad la sabría realizar.

Resumen: Deseo introducir el valor de una cookie en una variable.

Espero vuestras respuestas compañeros!!

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado hacer, al menos la parte crear y leer cookies para que tu pregunta muestre investigación.

Comment: Seria de mucha ayuda si colocas un extracto de codigo para entender bien el contexto de tu pregunta pero a modo de orientación, puedes ver algunos [ejemplos](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) para que sepas como utilizar cookies y para colocarla en tu input podrias utilizar algo como 
`document.querySelect('#input').value = getCookie('name')`;